# Why does the ADC report 0 in this sketch?

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, adc

This sketch always reports 0 for the ADC reading.

I think this is going to turn out to be something silly, but I cannot find the source. I've reviewed the sketch ADC lines carefully and they *seem* right, so maybe the problem with the physical connections or how I'm trying to report the ADC output or the order in which tasks are executed.  The `capture_FID()` etc functions are based on the example in Section 9.2.4 of Norman Dunbar's book, *Arduino Software Internals*.  The only difference is the position of `ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);` which I moved to right after the power up based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44357710/633251).  That did not make a difference.

```
void init();
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  capture_FID();
}
void loop() {
}

void capture_FID() {

  volatile uint16_t ADC_output = 0;  // max value 65536

  config_ADC();
  start_ADC();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    Serial.print("\ti = ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" value = ");
    Serial.println(ADC_output);
  }
  stop_ADC();
}

// ADC Configuration
void config_ADC() {
  Serial.println("Configuring the ADC...");
  PRR &= ~(1 << PRADC);                                            // power up the ADC
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);                                           // enable ADC
  ADCSRA = (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);             // slow the clock
  ADMUX = (0 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0);                             // use 5 V internal reference
  ADMUX &= ~(1 << ADLAR);                                          // right-align the 10 bit output in 2 byte/16 bit space
  ADMUX |= (0 << MUX3) | (0 << MUX2) | (0 << MUX1) | (0 << MUX0);  // multiplexer input; use A0
  DIDR0 |= (1 << ADC0D);                                           // disable digital input to pin A0
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIE);                                           // set interupt to notify data is available for further use
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADATE);                                          // auto-trigger on
  ADCSRB = 0;                                                      // free-running mode
  delay(20);                                                       // wait for voltage to settle
}

// Start the ADC = start acquiring data
void start_ADC() {
  Serial.println("Starting the ADC...");
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
}

// Stop the ADC = stop acquiring data
void stop_ADC() {
  Serial.println("Stopping the ADC...");
  ADCSRA |= (0 << ADSC);
}

ISR(ADC_vect) {
  volatile uint16_t ADC_output;  // max value 32767
  ADC_output = ADCW;
}
```

Hardware:

- Arduino R3
- 0.1 uF cap across GND and AREF
- PicoScope function generator is supplying a 500 Hz, 500 mV, 1 V offset signal; the negative output is wired to GND on the Arduino, the positive output is wired to A0.
- A sketch that doesn't involve free-running and auto-triggering that I found on Nick Gammon's site works fine, so the board appears to be fine.  This also implies the hardware connections and scope settings are fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* different variables named `ADC_output`:

- one which is local to `capture_FID()`, and is always zero (it is never
  assigned another value)
- one local to `ISR(ADC_vect)`, which is set but never used.

You should use only one such variable.

There are also a handful more problems in this code:

- `capture_FID()` prints multiple times the same result, without
  checking that new data has arrived
- access to `ADC_output` outside the ISR is not protected in a critical
  section
- the ADC register is called `ADC`, not `ADCW`.
- `ADCSRA |= (0 << ADSC)` is a no-op
- there is no point in declaring `init()`
- probably more, I did not read it thoroughly…

Comment: Ah, so my limited experience with C is the problem. Let me poke around a bit.  Thank you.